# Merging and change the column names of the merged ones

Tags: r, merge

How can I merge 2 data frame and then change the column name of the merged ones. See example below.

```
> DF1
  A    B  C
1 3  axe aa
2 6 base bb
3 9  lol cc

> DF2
  D  E   F
1 6 ss gun
2 3 dd run
3 9 vv fun

> merge(x=DF1,y=DF2, by.x="A",by.y="D",all.x=TRUE)
  A    B  C  E   F
1 3  axe aa dd run
2 6 base bb ss gun
3 9  lol cc vv fun
```

My question is how can I rename the merged ones the E and F into A.E and A.F
So it should be like this.

```
      A  B    C   A.E A.F
      3  axe  aa  dd  run
      6  base bb  ss  gun
      9  lol  cc  vv  fun
```

Comment: I mean automatically rename the columns from y into "A.MergedColumn". For example the A.E and A.F above.

Comment: I don't think you can do it via `merge`. You will need to `setNames` manually, something like `setNames(merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = "A", by.y = "D", all.x = TRUE), c(names(df1), paste0('A.', names(df2)[-1])))` - Given that the merged column of `DF2` is the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) which solves this very succintly.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)

eat(DF1, DF2, .by = c(A = "D"), .prefix = "A")
#   A    B  C A_E A_F
# 1 3  axe aa  dd run
# 2 6 base bb  ss gun
# 3 9  lol cc  vv fun
```

To have exactly the expected output we can use any renaming function in the
`.prefix` argument :

```
eat(DF1, DF2, .by = c(A = "D"), .prefix = ~paste0("A.",.))
#   A    B  C A.E A.F
# 1 3  axe aa  dd run
# 2 6 base bb  ss gun
# 3 9  lol cc  vv fun
```

`eat` is by default an enhanced left join, the `prefix` argument was designed precisely 
to address needs such as yours.