# Changing the column name of the column, by which is merged, to the name from the specified dataset

Tags: r, merge, data.table

If I have the following data.tables:

EDIT: changed `c`in `dt1` to `d` in order to prevent `dt1[dt2, on=.(col1= adapted_col1 )]` from being a solution to the problem.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(col1 = c("a", "b", "d"), 
                  col2 = 1:3, 
                  col3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

set.seed(1)
dt2 <- data.table(adapted_col1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
                  another_col = sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
                  and_anouther = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 10, replace = TRUE))
```

And I merge them as follows:

```
dt2[dt1, on=.(adapted_col1 = col1)]

    adapted_col1 another_col and_anouther col2  col3
 1:            a           3        FALSE    1  TRUE
 2:            a           8         TRUE    1  TRUE
 3:            a           8         TRUE    1  TRUE
 4:            b           2         TRUE    2 FALSE
 5:            b           7        FALSE    2 FALSE
 6:            b          10         TRUE    2 FALSE
 7:            b           4        FALSE    2 FALSE
 8:            c           4         TRUE    3 FALSE
 9:            c           5         TRUE    3 FALSE
10:            c           8         TRUE    3 FALSE
```

The column gets the name of the column name in `dt2`. As I will however do this merge repeatedly with `dt1`, I need the new data.table to have the column name from `dt1`. Can I change this?

The only solution I found is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921763/merging-and-change-the-column-names-of-the-merged-ones) which uses a different package, but I would rather just stay with data.table.

Comment: okay, stupid questionbut cant you just switch dt1 and dt2 in this case?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Well it does not really result in the same data haha..

Comment: arent they completely equivalent though? `dt1[dt2, on=.( col1 = adapted_col1)][order(col1, another_col, and_anouther),  
                                     .(col1, col2,  col3, another_col, and_anouther)]
dt2[dt1, on=.( adapted_col1 = col1)][order(adapted_col1, another_col, and_anouther),
                                     .(col1 = adapted_col1, col2,  col3, another_col, and_anouther)]`

Comment: In this specific example yes, but it does not really work for my actual data. If I want a solution for this specific example I could obviously just change the names manually. The whole point is to find a general solution. But maybe I should have created a better example then I guess (see edit).

Comment: Did the answer help you by any chance? If so, please mark it as accepted that the community is aware of it. Otherwise, point to what is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After clarification, I propose to write your own function for this:

```
correct_name_join <- function(dt1, dt2, ...){
  dots <- vapply(substitute(...()), deparse, NA_character_)
  dt <- dt1[dt2, on = dots]
  setnames(dt, old = names(dots), new = as.character(dots))
  return(dt)
}

correct_name_join(dt2, dt1, adapted_col1 = col1)
   col1 another_col and_anouther col2  col3
1:    a           3         TRUE    1  TRUE
2:    a           5         TRUE    1  TRUE
3:    a          10         TRUE    1  TRUE
4:    b           5        FALSE    2 FALSE
5:    b           7        FALSE    2 FALSE
6:    b           9        FALSE    2 FALSE
7:    d          NA           NA    3 FALSE

dt2[dt1, on=.(adapted_col1 = col1)]
   adapted_col1 another_col and_anouther col2  col3
1:            a           3         TRUE    1  TRUE
2:            a           5         TRUE    1  TRUE
3:            a          10         TRUE    1  TRUE
4:            b           5        FALSE    2 FALSE
5:            b           7        FALSE    2 FALSE
6:            b           9        FALSE    2 FALSE
7:            d          NA           NA    3 FALSE
```